# invoking WCF service with custombinding from a .Net standard client

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a legacy WCF service with custom binding. I want to invoke this service from a .Net Standard 2.0 client. I have added nuget packages system.servicemodel.primitives, system.servicemodel.security and system.servicemodel.security. Below is my channel factory setup

```
        var binding = new CustomBinding();
        var security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
        security.IncludeTimestamp = true;
        binding.Elements.Add(security);

        binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Default, Encoding.UTF8));
        binding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement { MaxBufferSize = MaxBufferSize, MaxReceivedMessageSize = MaxReceivedMessageSize });
        var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
        };
        var behaviour = new AddHttpHeaderMessageEndpointBehavior(headers);
        ChannelFactory<ITaskService> cf = new ChannelFactory<ITaskService>(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://api-xxl.yyy.com/cvg/fg/swer/v1"));
        cf.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(behaviour);
        cf.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
        cf.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

I get the below error

"HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'AzureApiManagementKey"

I am able to successfully invoke the API from a .Net Framework client. The only difference is

```
        binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(**MessageVersion.Soap12**, Encoding.UTF8));
```

Can someone advise me what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between these two code is TextMessageEncodingBindingElement MessageVersion attribute values.

The picture above is the default, the object returned the same as the Soap12WSAddressing10. Below need to make some changes. You can refer to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageversion.default?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) for further info.

Comment: I tried with all Message Version supported and it does not work. Yes, default is Soap12WSAddressing10.

Comment: You can check to see if there are any other differences in the code, if not, it may be a.NET standard 2.0 difference.

Comment: When i intercept the message with Fiddler i noticed that header is not getting passed. Please find below the raw request

POST https://api-xxl.yyy.com/cvg/fg/swer/v1 HTTP/1.1
Host: api-xxl.yyy.com
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1525

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass a behavior for the channel factory by implementing IEndpointBehavior with header details in constructor. Implement IClientMessageInspector and instantiate it from the custom behavior.
The `BeforeSendRequest()` of IClientMessageInspector  can be used to set the header for the request.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).